# How can I convert from vtkImageData (corresponding to an RGB image) to numpy?

Tags: numpy, vtk

I want to convert a vtkImageData (3 components) to numpy.

For a vtkImageData with 1 components, the following code works:

```
temp = vtk_to_numpy(data.GetPointData().GetScalars())
dims = data.GetDimensions()
numpy_data = temp.reshape(dims[2], dims[1], dims[0])
numpy_data = numpy_data.transpose(2,1,0)
```

However, when the number of components is 3, the above code provide a wrong image. How to fix it?

Update:

The following code work:

```
img_scalar = data.GetPointData().GetScalars()
dims = data.GetDimensions()
n_comp = img_scalar.GetNumberOfComponents()
temp = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(img_scalar)
numpy_data = temp.reshape(dims[1],dims[0],n_comp)
numpy_data = numpy_data.transpose(0,1,2)
numpy_data = np.flipud(numpy_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image has 3 components per pixel (RGB probably), then it's really a 4-d array, from the numpy standpoint.  So maybe it should be:

```
numpy_data = temp.reshape(dims[2], dims[1], dims[0], 3)
```

Comment: I have found the solution, and the code is updated.